# missing script: fabric-deps when installing caliper

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

I start using Hyperledger Caliper to analyse my Fabric blockchain.

I begin by using this doc https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1MtPSBgDXf3v7DicxTNr9srB0jGmdWew2tqvItJHculo/edit#slide=id.p8

when I try to excute :

```
npm run fabric-deps
```

I got:

> missing script: fabric-deps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial is outdated. Caliper has been published since to npm and Docker Hub. See the [official docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/vNext/installing-caliper/) for how to install Caliper.

Quick preview for globally installing Caliper:

```
npm install -g --only=prod @hyperledger/caliper-cli@0.1.0
caliper bind --caliper-bind-sut fabric --caliper-bind-sdk 1.4.4 --caliper-bind-args=-g
```